# Javascript not working onchange

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a simple html and JS script, but it doesn't fire the alert message onchange when I enter 2 in the input number field.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">       
        <script type="text/javascript">
                function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementById("partysize");
                if (x==2)   window.alert ("You entered" + x);
                }       
        </script>

    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#6BD3FF" text="#000000" link="#0000EE" vlink="#551A8B" alink="#FF0000">

        <div align="center">         
                  <br> Please enter the party size:
                  <input type="number" id = "partysize" name="partySize" onchange="myFunction()" >
                <br />
                <input type="SUBMIT" name="submitButton"> 
            </form>
            <br /> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: because x is an element....

Comment: the *element* isn't 2.  It's *value* is "2".

Comment: `if( x.value === '2'){ alert("You entered: " + x.value); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the value from the input box but in your snippet `x` is the only dom element. Pass the value to the change handler using `this.value`. Also `parseInt` will convert the number value in string to number

```js
function myFunction(x) {

  if (parseInt(x, 10) === 2) {
    alert("You entered" + x);
  }
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#6BD3FF" text="#000000" link="#0000EE" vlink="#551A8B" alink="#FF0000">

  <div align="center">
    <br> Please enter the party size:
    <input type="number" id="partysize" name="partySize" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton">

    <br />
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

ugh, fixed by getting the value of the element:

```
  function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementById("partysize").value;
                if (x==2)   window.alert ("You entered" + x);
                }
```

Comment: You're getting the value of the *element*.  The variables value is the *element*.